# How to sort the columns in the mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I am having column named `rating` in the mysql database table with multiple values from `1+,2+,................9+,10+,12+`. when i am sorting this column with query

```
select * from tbl_app order by rating desc
```

I am getting `9+` as highest value, can any one tell me how to get `12+` as highest value

Comment: one column has multiple value like "1+,2+,................9+,10+,12+"?

Comment: have you tried "ORDER BY rating + 1 desc"?

Comment: @JungsuHeo: Probably a single column that contains strings like `'1+'`, `'2+'`, ..., `'12+'`.

Comment: I gotta' ask why you're storing numbers as those funny looking strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT rating,SUBSTR(rating,1,LENGTH(rating)-1) FROM tbl_app ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(rating,1,LENGTH(rating)-1) as SIGNED) DESC;
```

if the last char is always a '+',the sql above will work.

Comment: The CAST will work but you don't really need the `substr` stuff, MySQL will ignore everything after the first non-numeric character when casting.

Comment: @muistooshort 3Q ~ i took a test as you say,it worked well,too.
I didn't know that before..Aha~
learn sth.,happy~

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
select convert(replace(rating,'+',' '),unsigned integer) as x from tab order by x desc
```

<kbd>[sql_fiddle_demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eb2f/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

what have you kept the datatype of the column rating ? If you have kept it varchar or text then this query will not work for sorting values as per descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do in MySQL is cast those odd looking strings to numbers:

```
order by cast(rating as unsigned) desc
-- or less explicitly
order by rating + 0 desc
```

Both of those casts will stop trying to convert the string to a number when they hit the `+` so you'll get them sorted numerically.

Simply removing the plus signs from the strings will still leave you with strings and `'10' < '2'` is just as true for strings as `'10+' < '2+'`. That's actually your whole problem: you're storing numbers as decorated strings when you should be storing them as integers and adding the `+` decorations when you display them. You really should fix your schema to make sense instead of adding ugly hacks to work around your schema's strange ideas.